# GDocs ImportHTML/XML not getting proper data

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a simple Google Spreadsheet's question.  I'm attempting to pull in a table and am not having luck with ImportHTML, it will only pull the first top cell and duplicates it somehow.  I also tried ImportXML, using XPath Helper to get the proper XPath, and it will not load the proper table data either.

Google Doc:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-toAivOhywZuErHK0LB5EADiMu_T9ZNUTgMhqFRBHOU/edit?usp=sharing

What I'm needing is the bottom table(id='player_gbs') on the following site:

```
http://www.forge-db.com/us/us18/players/profile/?server=us18&world=Sinerania&id=12497
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIuqc.jpg)

Here is what I've tried so far, this is all represented in the GDoc as well.

```
=ImportHTML(B1, "table", 2)
```

Returns the following line twice:
"Great Building Era Lvl FP  Req. FP FP Left 24h +"

```
=ImportXML(B1, "/html/body/div[@class='wrap']/div[@class='content'][2]/div[@class='b-box']")
```

Returns:

> "GB's with a new level in the last 24 hours are shown with a yellow 
>   background" Great BuildingEraLvlFPReq. FPFP Left24h +Great BuildingEraLvlFPReq. FPFP Left24h +"

Thinking the issue is that contained in the /div is `<thead> and <tfoot> before <tbody>` so I tried this XPath and just get N/A:

```
=ImportXML(B1, "/html/body/div[@class='wrap']/div[@class='content'][2]/div[@class='b-box']/div[@id='player_gbs_wrapper']/table[@id='player_gbs']/tbody")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that that table is created via JSON and javascript. If you view source on that page you'll see this chunk ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#player_gbs').dataTable( {
        "aLengthMenu": [[30], ['All']],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../../getPlayerGBs.php?id=12497&server=us18",
```

Which tells us that the data is coming from the following URL.
http://www.forge-db.com/us/us18/getPlayerGBs.php?id=12497&server=us18

That URL is providing the data that populates the table.

This script ([based off this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726282/google-spreadsheet-convert-multiple-columns-to-one-column)) will parse the data from that feed and write it to a sheet titled dataImport. It only gets the first two chunks of data, you'd just extend the loop to do more.

```
function urlDownload() {
var dataImport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('dataImport');
var apiPoint = "http://www.forge-db.com/us/us18/getPlayerGBs.php?id=12497&server=us18";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiPoint);
var response_json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
var length = response_json.data.length;
var a = [];
for(i=0; i<length; i++){
  dataImport.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.data[i][0])
  dataImport.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.data[i][1])

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I didn't even consider that, makes complete sense and your code was perfect.  Thanks again!