# Google Spreadsheet - Convert multiple columns to one column

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to loop through a set of rows in a Google Spreadsheet that look like this:

XXX  123   234   234

YYY  789   098   765

ZZZ  76    123   345

### End Result Needs to Be:

XXX: 123

XXX: 234

XXX: 234

YYY: 789

YYY: 098

etc.

My current code:

```
function loopshoplocations(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var data = sheet.getRange('A4:A8').getValues(); 
  var i=0; 
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    return ('Shop Location: ' + data[i][0]);
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes that there is a header row on row one. The data gets appended at the end of the sheet.  If you want something different, the code would need to be adjusted.

```
function loopshoplocations() {
  var data,L,outerArray,innerArray,numberOfRows,sheet,startRow;

  startRow = 2;

  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  numberOfRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  data = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numberOfRows-startRow+1,4).getValues(); 
  L = data.length;

  //Logger.log(data);

  outerArray = [];

  var i,j;
  for(i = 0; i < L; i++){

    for (j=1; j<4 ; j+=1) {//Begin count at one, not zero
      innerArray = [];//Reset
      innerArray.push(data[i][0]);
      innerArray.push(data[i][j]);
      //Logger.log(innerArray)
      outerArray.push(innerArray);
    };
  };

  sheet.getRange(numberOfRows+1,1,outerArray.length,outerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with a formula

```
=ArrayFormula( transpose(split(query(rept(left(A2:A, 3)&" ", 3),,50000), " "))&": "
&transpose(split(query(regexreplace(A2:A, "^(.+?)\s",""),,50000), " ")))
```

Also see this screenshot:

[image: SCREENSHOT]